# Digital Electronics

Tags: digital-logic

which steps should i take in finding the mod number that would decrease a signal of 2MHz to 0.4MHz.

Comment: This reeks of homework. What have you done to solve it on your own?

Comment: i divided 2 three times to get the number close to .4MHz which in result came to be .5MHz So i tried MOD 3 but its not making sense.

Comment: whats the second step?

Comment: this is not homework. im trying to study for my finals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide the frequency by the desired output frequency. 2 MHz / .4 MHz = 5